# How to use file upload in agile toolkit 4.2

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

Is there somewhere a full example of working atk4.2 filestore example code?

I've been searching in docs and stackoverflow and the few examples I have found just aren't working for me.

Do I need to extend `Model_File` or `Model_Filestore_File` ?

First gives me error

> Class is not defined in file

Second one gives

> Unable to include filestore/lib/Model/Filestore/File.php

What would be the simplest way to add file upload to CRUD?

Comment: So you want to know how to upload a file with PHP?

Comment: No. How to upload file with agiletoolkit framework using filestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have file upload, use the following in your model:

```
$this->add('filestore/Field_File','file_id');
```

the field should reference filestore_file.id. If you are looking to have a image upload with thumbnail, then:

```
$this->add('filestore/Field_Image','picture_id');
```

Once image is uploaded and form is submitted, the "id" of the file will be in respective field. For Field_Image it will also resize the thumbnail. You can further customize this by using your own image model:

```
    ->setModel('MyImage');

class Model_MyImage extends filestore\Model_Image {
    public $default_thumb_width=32;
    public $default_thumb_height=32;
}
```

This should work fine with 4.2.0, but the "development" branch is currently having some refinements which would allow to have multiple thumbnail sizes per image.

Comment: Thank You very much that works very well and I would'nt have figured it out myswelf in a million years.

Is there some simple mechanism for showing error when the file type is not supported? At the moment it just shows something like C:\fakepath\filename.xxx

Also feeling rather stupid by now but could You take a look at my view Grid and give me some pointers how to add the file link on there [link](https://gist.github.com/2636918)

Comment: With the power of inheritance, you can override any method or any property inside your model. Model is responsible for importing so you can either create a new type in there or instruct user about a problem by throwing exception with `throw $this->exception('wrong file type');`