# How to display image from filestore/Field_Image in agiletoolkit?

Tags: php, models, atk4, agiletoolkit

I have a model `Profile`

```
<?php

class Model_Profile extends Model_Table {
public $table = 'profile';

function init(){
    parent::init();

     ...

    $m = $this->add('filestore/Field_Image');
  }
}
```

Now in my `index.php`, i am trying to set the full image path in the template.

```
$m = $this->add('Model_Profile')->loadBy('user_id',$this->api->auth->get('id'));

//Here i want to var_dump the full image path example (/admin/upload/0/20131123014011__photo-on-23-11-2013-at-01.36.jpg)
```

This displays me the image id from the table filestore_file.

```
die('Filestore image:' . $m->get('filestore_field_image'));
```

Discussion related to this topic:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/agile-toolkit-devel/i-i9OK4Ya1A

I tried this

```
$fm = $this->add('filestore/Field_Image')->load($m->get('filestore_field_image'));
var_dump($fm->getThumbURLExpr());
```

but it threw an exception

Other links :

[FileStore step by step example with 4.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755700/filestore-step-by-step-example-with-4-2-1)

[How to use file upload in agile toolkit 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496584/how-to-use-file-upload-in-agile-toolkit-4-2)

[How to use Filestore in API in Agiletoolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472132/how-to-use-filestore-in-api-in-agiletoolkit/20157742#20157742)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, its like this:

```
$m = $this->add('Model_Profile')->loadBy('user_id',$this->api->auth->get('id'));

$mf = $this->add('filestore/Model_File');
$mf->load($m->get('filestore_field_image'));
var_dump($mf->get('url'));
```